# Cannot declare an array in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script **my_script.sh** as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello There"
# declare arrays
declare -a my_array
```

When I run it using **sh my_script.sh** I get:

```
Hello There
': not a valid identifiermy_array
```

When I run it using **/bin/bash my_script.sh** I get:

```
Hello There
': not a valid identifiermy_array
```

How do I run this script?

Comment: You've got CRLFs -- DOS newlines. It's not specific to arrays -- that'll cause _lots_ of things to fail.

Comment: BTW, the giveaway that that's the problem is that a carriage return, when printed to the terminal, causes the cursor to go to the leftmost column and start overwriting previously-printed text.

Comment: (Also, any script that uses bash-only features should only be run with `bash`, not `sh`; even when sh is a symlink to bash, it turns off some features for closer POSIX compliance when invoked under that name).